# Accessing Help without having to edit page

Tags: web-part, help

I'm trying to implement a context sensitive help system within SharePoint.  The built in Help system requires you to edit the page before you can see Web Part help.  I want my users to be able to click on a help link without going to edit mode.  Ideally, I would want a help icon to appear in the title of a Web part but I can't find any way of doing that.

Comment: Use JavaScript to add a SPAN tag with the icon inside the WebPart Title DIV, attach an onclick handler that opens your Help (in a nice SharePoint Modal Dialog)